# Database *data* version migration tool

Tags: database, version-control, postgresql

I have two db servers: local and remote (dev).

Remote dev version is being constantly changed including the app static data.

While working on my copy I need to modify not only schema but also static data (like fill recently added columns) and then deploy my changes to dev. The problem here is that I can't just overwrite static data there because I always have outdated static data in my local copy. So I need to synchronize it between databases: push my changes there and apply their changes here.

So is there a tool which I can use?

Comment: Does the tool need to be open source or commercial? What is the database used (mysql, sql server, etc.)?

Comment: @kenchew open source is better but it doesn't matter much. db - postgresql.